# Correct way to use - and ,

Tags: commas

1. observed in almost any country, both rich and poor OR
2. observed in almost any country — both rich and poor OR
3. observed in almost any country, both the rich and the poor

Comment: These are fragments, not sentences.  More is needed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: 1 and 3 have the same use of the comma.